# SetInterval Javascript not working- showing blank

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a clock that will update itself every second.
For some reason when I try to run the code I get a blank page.

this is the Javascript part:

```
function test()
{
    var today = new Date();

    var day = today.getDate();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    var year = today.getFullYear();

    var hr = today.getHours();
    var mins = today.getMinutes();
    var sec = today.getSeconds();

    document.body.innerHTML = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "   " + hr + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
}

setInterval(test, 1000);
```

this is the HTML part:

```
<html lang="en">

    <head>
    </head>

    <body name="body">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS-test.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

I've tried a few other variations and none seam to work.
How do I fix it to actually display something?
thanks in advance.
(I am a newbie in javascript)

Comment: Script in `<pre>` tag ?

Comment: Have you checked the browser dev console for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change secs to sec

```
 var sec = today.getSeconds();

    document.body.innerHTML = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "   " + hr + ":" + mins + ":" + sec;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little change in your function...

```
  document.onload=setInterval(test,1000);
```

and do the sec/secs change in your variable declaration

Answer (score 0):

The script should be written within `<script></script>`
and secondly, its `sec` not `secs` in your last statement of that function.. It works fine.

```js
function test()
{
    var today = new Date();

    var day = today.getDate();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    var year = today.getFullYear();

    var hr = today.getHours();
    var mins = today.getMinutes();
    var sec = today.getSeconds();

    document.body.innerHTML = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "   " + hr + ":" + mins + ":" + sec;
}

setInterval(test, 1000);
```